# Update em alguns campos Laravel 4.2

Tags: mysql, laravel

Eu tenho uma tabela chamada People no Mysql com 40 campos e eu quero fazer update em apenas 2 campos (latitude and longitude) mas não quero trazer todos os 40 campos pra alterar junto. Só quero salvar os 2 campos que mencionei.

```
$people = DB::table('people')
            ->where('people.id', $people_id)
            ->select('people.id', 'people.latitude', 'people.longitude')
            ->first();

$people->latitude = $latitude;
$people->longitude = $longitude;
$people->save();
```

Como fazer isso com Laravel 4.2?

Comment: Traduza para o português sua pergunta

Comment: Faça a tradução para portugues por favor

Comment: Deu certo pra você Bruno?

Answer (score 0):

Não precisa trazer todos os campos existem uma maneira de fazer isso dando apenas o `update` em alguns campos definidos:

[Exemplo que está na documentação](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queries#updates)

```
DB::table('users')
        ->where('id', 1)
        ->update(array('votes' => 1));
```

---

No seu caso:

```
DB::table('people')
       ->where('id', $people_id)
       ->update(array('latitude'=>$latitude,'longitude'=>$longitude));
```

[Veja documentação completa da versão Laravel 4.2](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queries#updates)